# Java - current time in different time-zones

Tags: java, time, calendar, timezone, utc

I want to create a thread, that will write current time in difference zones every second. This is what I came up with:

```
class TimeThread extends Thread {
    String city;
    String belt;

    public TimeThread(String city, String belt) {
        this.city = city;
        this.belt = belt;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (; ; ) {
            String s = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + belt)).getTime().toString();
            int i = s.indexOf(":");
            System.out.println(city + ": " + s.substring(i - 2, i + 6));
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All threads show the same time. What's wrong with this code?

And by the way, how to use UTC standard?

Thank you.

Comment: You use `calendar.getTime().toString()` which will always print the same time in your system timezone - hence no difference. Use a formatter object like `SimpleDateFormat` and set the timezone there, then you will see different local times.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat does work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible problems.

**1. Identifying the Time Zone**

`TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + belt)` returns the specified TimeZone, or the GMT zone if the given ID cannot be understood. [[1]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29) Make sure `belt` contains the correct identifier.

**2. Printing the Date**

`Calendar.getTime()` returns a Date representing the time value. The documentation doesn't state if it will use the given time zone or may use any equal representation. [[2]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) Therefore you should use [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) to get the required String representation.

Another advantage is that you won't need to manipulate the String with `substring(..)` any more.

**Example Code**

```
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + belt);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timezone);

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z");
formatter.setCalendar(calendar);
formatter.setTimeZone(timezone);
String s = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
```

**Side note**

Notice that your code may skip a second, because retrieving the time and formatting it needs time to run, so that each loop iteration will take longer than 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question: why `calendar` has the same value after initizalization and doesn't update every usage, every `getTime()` method call?

Comment: @EdAkhmetshin: `Calendar` is not only a calendar representation, but also an instant in time, therefore it won't update automatically. On instantiation the current time will be set.

Comment: I have no reputation enough for the voting, sorry.